# Cargar una imagen cuando finalice la carga de otra

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo muchas imágenes pero el cargarlas se relentiza la página, y lo que necesito es que cargue la primera imagen al 100% y luego comience a cargar la siguiente, y que el ciclo se repita hasta que todas las imagines estén cargadas.

Por ejemplo:

```
<div class="imagenes">
<img src="pequena1.png">  
<img src="pequena2.png">
<img src="pequena3.png">  
</div>
```

Lo importante es que la siguiente imagen cargue automaticamente "solo" después de que la anterior este cargada al 100%, de esta manera no se sobrecargara la página.

El número de imágenes puede variar, por lo tanto sería bueno que detectara la etiqueta `<img>` incluidos en un `<div>` determinado.

Algún tipo de bucle, pero se detenga hasta que la última imagen este cargada.

Comment: Hola! En vez de cargar las imágenes al modo tradicional con HTML, podrías hacerlo con Javascript. Allí puedes hacer el ciclo o bucle, detectando que cada vez que una imagen se carga (evento load de cada imagen), recién le envíes el href de la siguiente...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Una solución sencilla sería cargar las imágenes una a una, no usando su `src` sino un data-atributo, e ir sustituyendo el `src` de la imagen sólo cuando se haya cargado la imagen anterior (usando el [evento `onLoad` de la imagen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/image.onload) para ello). Para ello podrías usar una función simple que lea las imágenes, las guarde en una lista y las vaya cargando en orden.

Algo como esto:

```
// lista de imágenes a cargar (las que tengan data-src)
var imagenesACargar = document.querySelectorAll("img[data-src]");
// total de imágenes cargadas
var totalImagenesCargadas = -1;

// función que carga la siguiente imagen de la lista
function cargarImagenesUnaAUna() {
  // avanzamos a la siguiente imagen de la lista
  totalImagenesCargadas++;
  // si existe (aún quedan imágenes)
  if (imagenesACargar[totalImagenesCargadas]) {
    // le asignamos esta función al evento onload
    imagenesACargar[totalImagenesCargadas].onload = cargarImagenesUnaAUna;
    // cambiamos el src por el valor del data-atributo
    imagenesACargar[totalImagenesCargadas].src = imagenesACargar[totalImagenesCargadas].dataset.src;
  }
}
```

Para evitar inconvenientes con imágenes vacías, sería bueno que le pusieras un `src` a las imágenes con un pixel transparente o algo. De ese modo no tendrías llamadas innecesarias al servidor o posibles problemas 404.

Aquí puedes ver una demo funcionando:

```js
var imagenesACargar = document.querySelectorAll("img[data-src]");
var totalImagenesCargadas = -1;

function cargarImagenesUnaAUna() {
  totalImagenesCargadas++;
  if (imagenesACargar[totalImagenesCargadas]) {
    imagenesACargar[totalImagenesCargadas].onload = cargarImagenesUnaAUna;
    imagenesACargar[totalImagenesCargadas].src = imagenesACargar[totalImagenesCargadas].dataset.src;
  }
}

cargarImagenesUnaAUna();
```

```html
<img src="" data-src="https://placehold.it/200x200/" />
<img src="" data-src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200" />
<img src="" data-src="https://placehold.it/300x200/" />
```

---

El mismo código transformado a un mini-plugin de jQuery (como se menciona en los [comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/145965/cargar-una-imagen-cuando-finalice-la-carga-de-otra/146165#comment274930_146165)):

```js
$.fn.cargaImagenesUnaAlTiempo = function() {
  let imagenesACargar = $(this).find("img[data-src]");
  let totalImagenesCargadas = -1;

  function cargarImagenesUnaAUna() {
    totalImagenesCargadas++;
    if (imagenesACargar[totalImagenesCargadas]) {
      $(imagenesACargar[totalImagenesCargadas]).on("load", cargarImagenesUnaAUna);
      $(imagenesACargar[totalImagenesCargadas]).attr("src", $(imagenesACargar[totalImagenesCargadas]).data("src"));
    }
  }
  
  cargarImagenesUnaAUna()
};

$("#midiv").cargaImagenesUnaAlTiempo();
$("#midiv2").cargaImagenesUnaAlTiempo();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="midiv">
  <img src="" data-src="https://placehold.it/200x200/" />
  <img src="" data-src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200" />
  <img src="" data-src="https://placehold.it/300x200/" />
</div>

<div id="midiv2">
  <img src="" data-src="https://placehold.it/300x300/" />
  <img src="" data-src="https://lorempixel.com/400/300" />
  <img src="" data-src="https://placehold.it/300x300/" />
</div>
```

Aunque no sé si esto es lo que tenías en mente. La idea es que ahora puedes llamar a la función `cargaImagenesUnaAlTiempo` desde jQuery seleccionando el elemento al que quieres que se aplique. Por ejemplo, si quieres que las imágenes de `#div-con-imagenes` se carguen una a una, entonces harías `$("#div-con-imagenes").cargaImagenesUnaAlTiempo()`.

Comment: Exelente, basicamente es lo que estaba nesecitando, muchas gracias y esta respuesta es altamente recomendada. Ahora,solo tengo 2 cositas pendientes: 1-hay algun modo de agregar la imagen src con algun js, para no tener que ponerlo en todas las imagenes. 2- hay algun modo de que se limite o especifique que las imgenes a cargar estan dentro de un div y asi no tener que cambiar el src?

Comment: @Manuelb para el punto 2, lo único que tendrías que hacer es cambiar el selector. Por ejemplo, ahora mismo es `img[data-src]` que seleccionará todas las imágenes de la página que tengan un atributo "data-src", pero si quieres que sólo lo haga para las imágenes que estén dentro de por ejemplo el div con id "midiv", entonces el selector sería algo como esto `#midiv img[data-src]`. Como puedes ver es bastante sencillo.

Comment: @Manuelb no termino de comprender a qué te refieres en el punto 1. ¿Podrías describirlo con más detalle?

Comment: Olvidalo,es solo algo para la estetica en el codigo, pero ya perdio importancia. Ahora, podrias enseñarme la equivalencia del codigo pero en jquery, e encontrado que el uso de javascript es limitado en navegadores viejos, y la insercion de jquery es una ventaja. Me has sorprendido lo basico y potente de la solucion que aportas,pero se podria hacer lo mismo facil, basico y practico en jquery?

Comment: @Manuelb he creado un pequeño plugin de jQuery que hace eso mismo. No sé si es lo que buscas (y seguramente se puede hacer mejor) pero funciona.

Comment: mmm... donde consigo el plugins ejjejejeje. O si puedes, coloca el codigo, yo lo probare sin demora y te digo.

Comment: @Manuelb el plugin es la última edición que le hice a la respuesta.

Comment: Exelente, justamente lo que buscaba, si pudiera darte mas puntos lo haria jejejeee.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74630/discussion-between-manuel-b-and-alvaro-montoro).

Comment: Un pequeño problema, tengo publicado muchas entradas y editar todo el codigo de las img en cada entrada para colocar el "data-src" no es nada practico. 

He agregado este pequeño codigo en el inicio en un intento de solucion:

    var base = $("#midiv img").attr("src");
    var preCarga = $("img").attr("data-src", base);

El resultado es que crea el "data-src" en la imagen y ejecuta el resto del puglin, pero solo carga la primera imagen y no logro que cargue el src correspondiente a cada imagen.

Answer (score 3):

Podrías utilizar el plugin [Lazy Load](https://appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/), según el scroll de como la página vaya avanzando, las diferentes imágenes se cargarán, así podrías evitar la relentización de la página hacia el usuario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[DEMO](https://appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled/)

Comment: La demo me lleva a un enlace que está roto.

Comment: @FranciscoRomero Listo, ya se está el enlace bien.